# Is there any table which we can refer to get the partition name in Azure?

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

I want to know the partition name (similar to PART_NAME in Hive) of the table that has been partitioned specifically on Azure, I've been looking in the System tables (like sys.partitions) for this information but was not able to figure it out, therefore wanted to ask is there any other system tables which I can refer to get the detail about the partition name.

To make the question more clear I've added a screen shot. In the photo I've highlighted a column name on which partition is being performed, I want to retrieve that column name, so is there any way to retrieve that from any System tables?[image: Sample Table Structure]

Answer (score 0):

You have to join a bunch of tables together to get worthwhile Partition information. Here is a sample:

```
SELECT s.[name] AS [schema]
   ,t.[name] AS [table]
   , i.[name] AS [index_name]
   , p.[partition_id]
   , p.[partition_number]
   , p.[rows] AS [partition_rows]
   , rng.[value] AS [partition_value]
   , ds.[data_space_id]
   , ps.[function_id]
    from sys.tables t
        join sys.schemas s
            on s.[schema_id] = t.[schema_id]
        join sys.indexes i
            on t.[object_id] = i.[object_id]
        join sys.partitions p
            on  p.[object_id] = t.[object_id]
        join sys.data_spaces ds  
            on  i.[data_space_id] = ds.[data_space_id]
        join sys.partition_schemes ps
            on ps.[data_space_id] = i.[data_space_id]
        join sys.partition_functions pf  
            on  ps.[function_id] = pf.[function_id]
        join sys.partition_range_values rng 
            on pf.[function_id] = rng.[function_id] AND rng.[boundary_id] = p.[partition_number]
    where s.[name] = @schema_name
    and t.[name] = @table_name
```

Which returns something like the following:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply, does the index_name column here depict the partition name?

Comment: I'm not sure a Partition gets a name so much - my experience is in Synapse (formerly SQLDW), and Partitions are Ranges (left or right) rather than distinct values. For my purposes, I use partition_value to determine which partition. There are other columns available in those tables as well, so you may need to dig a little deeper to find what you are after.